# PHP Explode array using integer field

Tags: php, mysql

I searched, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere here. I have a multiselect box that will take each selection and explode it into individual data entries into a MySQL DB. Here is the code

```
   $arr = explode(",",$values["account_id"]);
   $j = count($arr);
   for($i = 0; $i < $j ; $i++)
{
  $strInsert = "update accounts_data set balance=balance+".$values["debit"]." where id='".$arr[$i]."'";
  DB::Query($strInsert);
}
```

The field account_id is an integer field, but if I have more than 2 items selected, the code breaks. If account_id is set to a VARCHAR, I can select everything and it works just as I need it to updating every account balance with the new debit. I'm not quite sure why it works for a VARCHAR and not an INT, and I can't quite figure out how to make it work after a month of trial and error. I was wondering if anyone had an idea that is smarter than I am.

Comment: have you tried to echo the query before testing?what is the output?

Comment: What _exactly_ does `$values["account_id"]` contain?

Comment: If I echo the query, it's just blank. No output at all. The $values["account_id"] is the data from the multiselect box, which is account numbers.

Comment: give us a real sample of $values["account_id"] of account numbers that break it, and another that works.  Would also be helpful to know mysql table structure

Comment: This is also not a bank. It's used on an internal network for client billing, one that's not connected to the internet at all.

Comment: $values["account_id"] is simply just a number such as 32, 82, 107, etc. Just an account number. This value is obtained from a multiselect box. Lets say I want to add a monthly charge of $100 to 60 accounts, I would select the 60 accounts from the multiselect box, and that's where it gets the data from.

accounts_data table structure is of id is an int(6).
If I select 2 accounts, it works. If I select more then 2 accounts, the output for account_id is blank since it's an INT field in MySQL. If its made as a VARCHAR, it works.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understood about your explanation about varchar and int.

Here is a way I would do it:

```
$values["account_id"] = "30,56,78";
$values["debit"] = 100;

foreach(explode(",", $values["account_id"]) as $account)   
{
    $strInsert = "update accounts_data set balance=balance+" . $values["debit"] ." where id=" . $account;
    echo $strInsert . PHP_EOL;
    //   DB::Query($strInsert);
}
```

Hope this helps something.

Comment: Same thing happens. If I select 2 accounts, it shows this:
````update accounts_data set balance=balance+100 where id=24
update accounts_data set balance=balance+100 where id=25 
````

If I select 3 or more accounts, I get the error: Column 'account_id' cannot be null

Comment: Can you post the exact value of $values["account_id"] and the exact error you are getting, please?

Comment: The exact value is just numbers, such as above where I posted id=24, or id=25. If I select 2 accounts, it will work as it should. But 3 or more and it drops all the account_id's that are selected from the multiselect box. I get an error that the account_id cannot be null, as it's not selecting any numbers. The "ID" field on accounts_data is an INT type column. If I change the column type to a VARCHAR, it will work.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but it looks like your variable $values["account_id"] may me the issue; do you have an extra empty line/value? And you last explanation validates this, since the last insert (if there was an extra empty value/line from your multiselect) would pass if your column was varchar...(it would not update anything), but if its integer, it breaks. Have you tried printing all the sql statements when you have 3 or more values?

Comment: I made it basic to just insert instead of update just to try, and if 3 or more are selected, the printed sql doesn't show anything. If I select just 2 accounts, SQL prints this: insert into accounts_data (id) values ('25')   insert into accounts_data (id) values ('26').
I'm not sure if it makes any difference, but I'm using PHPRunner to make the script that I need. But I'm doing this as free coding and not from the software itself. So the value of account_id is from PHPRunners field.